# Prolog list issue

Tags: prolog

I have the following rules:

```
/*The structure of a subject teaching team takes the form: 
  team(Subject, Leader, Non_management_staff, Deputy). 
 Non_management_staff is a (possibly empty) list of teacher 
structures and excludes the teacher structures for Leader and 
Deputy. 
teacher structures take the form:  
 teacher(Surname, Initial,  
       profile(Years_teaching,Second_subject,Club_supervision)). 
   Assume that each teacher has his or her team's Subject as their  
 main subject.*/  

team(computer_science,teacher(may,j,profile(20,ict,model_railways)), 
 [teacher(clarke,j,profile(32,ict,car_maintenance))], 
 teacher(hamm,p,profile(11,ict,science_club))).

team(maths,teacher(vorderly,c,profile(25,computer_science,chess)), 
 [teacher(o_connell,d,profile(10,music,orchestra)), 
  teacher(brankin,p,profile(20,home_economics,cookery_club))], 
 teacher(lynas,d,profile(10,pe,football))). 

team(english,teacher(brewster,f,profile(30,french,french_society)), 
 [ ], 
 teacher(flaxman,j,profile(35,drama,debating_society))). 

 team(art,teacher(lawless,m,profile(20,english,film_club)), 
 [teacher(walker,k,profile(25,english,debating_society)), 
  teacher(brankin,i,profile(20,home_economics,writing)), 
  teacher(boyson,r,profile(30,english,writing))],
  teacher(carthy,m,profile(20,music,orchestra))).
```

I am supposed to bring back the initial and surname of any leader in a team that contains a total of 2 or more teachers with ict as their second subject.

I am new to prolog so unsure of this.  Also, I have gotten back the results correctly but it is being returned 3 times.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, my aplogies if this is terribly easy.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code you use to find these teachers, so I can't say for sure, but if there were a team with 3 members w/ ict as their second subject (for example, computer_science), then there would be 3 ways to find 2 (AB, AC, and BC), which would explain your multiple results.  But saying how to modify your code to fix that would require seeing the code to be fixed.

Comment: answer(Name, Init) :- team(_, Lead, Staff, Dep),
 Lead = teacher(Name, Init, _),
 Person = teacher(_, _, profile(_, ict, _)),
 member(Person, [Lead, Dep | Staff]),
 member(teacher(_,_, profile(_, ict, _)), [Lead, Dep |   Staff]).